# MetaMask Not showing the Test Networks

Tags: ether, metamask

[image]

I have installed the metamask chrome plugin . I am unable to see the different test networks in the metamask. Need help how this can be solved

Answer (score 1):

Try Settings > Advanced > Show test networks

Comment: networks are showing in the advanced with locked icon, but not showing the drop down

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Click on metamask plugin icon
2. Click on your metamask account icon
3. Then select setting and go to advance setting
4. Scroll down and on test network radio button

Now, you can see you test network along with your main network.